# Authentication and Authorization in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, authorization

- Purpose of **Authentication Handlers**? I implemented Authentication Handlers, but they were not working until I started using Authorize attribute on controller/methods. Else my handler would get invoked and return authentication fail result but even after that request would continue its flow and return data from API? Why do we require to use Authorize attribute with authentication Handlers?
- Purpose of **Authorize attribute/ Authorize filters**? I know its simply used to implement authorization, but then what about **Authorization Policy**?

Are these supposed to work in a flow explained by Request Middleware pipelines?
Like I need to implement
1)Authentication Using Handlers and different Schemes as per my requirement
2)Authorization Policies and then finally Authorization attributes and filters

And then this whole authentication and authorization will be driven by authorize attribute only.
Or is their any way to drive authentication alone?

Answer (score 0):

> Purpose of Authentication Handlers? I implemented Authentication Handlers, but they were not working until I started using Authorize attribute on controller/methods. Else my handler would get invoked and return authentication fail result but even after that request would continue its flow and return data from API? Why do we require to use Authorize attribute with authentication Handlers?

Authentication is used to validate a user’s credentials,  and Authorization is used to grant access to one or more resources of the application to a user.

In popular terms, Authentication is a lock, Authorization is to give you the key, get the key to open the lock. Without Authorization, Authentication is meaningless, and everyone can't access it or everyone can.

> Purpose of Authorize attribute/ Authorize filters? I know its simply used to implement authorization, but then what about Authorization Policy?

ASP.NET Core has both role-based and policy-based Authorization. In general, role-based Authorization is sufficient. But as roles become more segmented, it will become more complex. This is where policy-based Authorization comes in, which provides a flexible, reusable, and extensible security model. A policy consists of multiple requirements that contain data parameters that verify the user's identity.

Specific working methods and example code can be found in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and [this article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/development/dotnet-development/policy-based-authorization-in-asp-net-core-a-deep-dive/#:%7E:text=Role%2Dbased%20Authorization%20in%20ASP.NET%20Core&text=You%20can%20specify%20the%20roles,controller%20or%20an%20action%20method.).

Hope this helps you.

Comment: And Is their any way to drive authentication alone rather than using Authorization attribute or implementing a custom- middleware

Comment: When you say drive authentication alone, do you mean to create your own method interface for authentication? What is the purpose of doing so?

Comment: I want to drive authentication alone, but without using Authorize Attribute, If I don't use the attribute my Application does not generate a 401 Unauthorized response.
The requirement is simple, only authenticate the request (I.e , check if the user is valid or not if not send a 401)

Comment: You can use customize the behavior of [AuthorizationMiddleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/customizingauthorizationmiddlewareresponse?view=aspnetcore-5.0) or [AllowAnonymousAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.allowanonymousattribute?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to forbid responses or specifiy the methods need no authorization.

Comment: Yes, I think that's my only option. Thanks!